# How to zoom image in irregular ploygon shape in web languages.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, image, css

All Image zooming in algorithm/scripts i found via google are limited to zooming a square of rectangular portion of image.

I've a high quality image like this (800x600) : [image: This image will be of high quality]

I want to zoom only the orange portion in 800x600 aspect ratio.
By doing this the image will be stretched from point 2 and 3 but it is no problem for me...
 The resulting image will be : [image: Zoomed and stretched image]

I want to do this in web languages like Javascript/Jquery/css or any other that can be implemented on a php page like flash...

I'll be specifying four pixels for 1(x,y), 2(x,y), 3(x,y) and 4(x,y) for the image zooming (if it is possible else you suggest how should I specify four points in image).

After doing this i also want to do this vice versa..

Any help from you in this matter???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In AS3 you can use a class like [DistortImage](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage) which tesselates your image into triangles and scale them.

Comment: Hey thanks... seems some type of help... i'll surely search more in this matter...